# Scheduling an existing AWS EC2 instance to start/stop

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling

Right now I am using the [Auto Scaling Command Line Tool](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/2535) to launch a new EC2 instance once per day and run a script that terminates itself upon completion. Now I need to do the same thing with a different script, but this one requires several Python modules to be installed. Therefore, I would like to schedule the start/stop of a *single, existing* instance rather than the launch/termination of a brand new instance. I've scoured Amazon's documentation/blogs but I can't determine if this functionality is supported with Autoscaling. How could this be accomplished?

Comment: I disagree, I don't think this issue is too broad.  I have the same issue.  AS won't start/stop your instances only launch/terminate.  The way I'm acheiving this is to use the `suspend-processes` aws-cli command and suspending `HealthCheck ReplaceUnhealthy` processes.  Then I can create a cron script to easily start/stop the instances of the autoscaling group without worry of auto-termination since the instance is unhealthy.  Please open the question up so I can post this answer in full..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My eventual solution was to set up an instance the way I wanted and then create an AMI from it. My autoscaling setup then starts/stops an instance of that AMI.

Answer (score 2):

Its not supported with autoscaling. If you want to keep doing what you are currently doing. You could install the python modules with a cloud init script.

You can also start/stop an existing instance with the command line tools, just not the autoscaling ones.